# How to expend $\log_a(\log_ax)$ for $a\in(0;1) \land x\in(0;1)$?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, approximation

Here are some logarithm rules :

- $\log_ay=\frac{\ln y}{\ln a}$
- $\log_a(A\cdot B)=\log_aA+\log_aB$
- $\frac{1}{\ln a}=\log_ae$

Hence:
$$\log_a(\log_ax)=\log_a \left(\frac{1}{\ln a}\cdot \ln x\right) = \log_a(\log_ae)+\log_a(\ln x)
$$

**The problem**: $\ln a<0 \vee \log_ae<0$ to choose- the argument of $\log_a$ is negative. $\ln x$ as well.

---

Origin of the question: $\log_ax=a^x$

[image]

A sample way to solve: $\log_a(\log_ax)=x$

I am not sure if I can say: $\log_ax=\frac{|\ln x|}{|\ln a|}$

Comment: See my edits to this question and to the answer below for proper MathJax usage.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I see the different (of course it's nice)- I don't know where or how set MathJax 'ON'. I understand to fix my typos (thank you) but the LaTex default front is not my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\ln a$ and $\ln x$ are negative- we can solve via the complex logarithm:
$$ \ln(r\cdot e^{i\theta})=\ln r+i\theta
$$
Trick: $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Hence:
$$ \ln(-r)= \ln r+i\pi
$$
For better calculating:
$$ \ln(y)\rightarrow  \ln(|y|)+i\pi ;y<0
$$
This way:
$$\log_a(\log_ax)=\frac{1}{\ln a}\cdot \ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\right) = \frac{1}{\ln a} \cdot [\ln(\ln x)-\ln(\ln a)]
$$

Note that:$$
\ln(\ln x)-\ln(\ln a)=\ln(|\ln x|)+i\pi-(\ln(|\ln a|)+i\pi)=\ln(|\ln x|)-\ln(|\ln a|)
$$

Hence:
$$\log_a(\log_ax)=\frac{1}{\ln a}\cdot [\ln(|\ln x|)-\ln(|\ln a|)]
$$